# SCCM "Create Task Sequence Media" not enough space

Tags: sccm

I am getting the following error in SCCM when trying to create USB media:

[image: Error 1.]

In the CreateTSMedia log for this task I get:

[image: Error 2.]

Which indicates that there is not enough space in the destination or staging area.   STaging area is sort of hard set to c:\users\user, and I have the destination pointing to D:

[image: Free space.]

You can see in the initial image that the total size of all the content in the sequence is just over 4Gb, and the drive with the smallest amount of space free has over 55Gb, and yet I still get "not enough free space" errors.

Everything online just say, clear some space.   But I already have plenty, something else is going on here.

Comment: Probably not really the reason in 2022 but I assume your Drives are NTFS formatted and not FAT32 for some compatibility reason?

Comment: Thanks for the response mate, appreciate anyone responding to this.  The thing is, the process formats the drive for you, so this should be a self-correcting process.   I will give this a go though as I have nothing else to go on here so far.

Comment: So I have seen an issue that your suggestion has uncovered!  This 32Gb USB disk could only be formatted as a 511 Mb volume.   I think the actual USB stick was knackered.   I am unable to test this further though, as now the "create task sequence media" button is completely gone, even after upgrading the console and rebooting.   Can't find any information about this online either.

Comment: Ok, that sounds really strange. Never seen this but I sometimes had problems where buttons in the Ribbon did not really appear (though always fixed after a restart) Is it also missing if you right click the "Task Sequences" node directly in the console?

Comment: Ok so this was because I was not logged in with my admin account.  Button is there as admin.  I am trying to build the resulting iso in a drive with almost 500 Gb free on it, and it is still reporting not enough space.  I have even tried a different task sequence, one that has worked previously, still says not enough space on the 500 Gb target.